# How to use Razor Layout as Master Page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 and have some parts written using aspx.
So in some of my views I have something like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Thread.Index" %>
```

But I've already create Layout for site using Razor's Layout and I want to use that layout in this .aspx file too.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: So you want to use a Razor layout file as a master page for a view coded using the aspx view engine?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to have both layout and master page in my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use Razor layouts with WebForms views. You will need to create a WebForms masterpage for WebForms views. View engines cannot be mixed like this.

Answer (score 13):

I recently blogged about this at here,

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/09/01/a-webform-view-with-a-razor-layout-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration, which I used to solve my problem. This approach can be modified to host a WebForms Page inside an MVC Master Layout. Sorta kinda totally cool. (For those suckers who need to mix WebForms and MVC pages.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can not mix the 2 different view engines (The Razor view engine and the old ASPX view engine).